# Can Ghouls drink water?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I just started watching the series and I'm about 4episodes in.

In episode 2 the shopkeeper old guy says:

> Since ancient times, coffee is the one thing that ghouls and humans can enjoy.

but in episode 4 when Touka got a piece of meat from a friend, she was in the bathroom drinking water and fighting to keep it in her body.

She didn't instantly vomit from the water but in episode 1 when the protagonist drank milk he did.

So based off of these observations, can ghouls actually drink water & coffee? And if so are there other dietary things that float along this median line of edibility among both races?

Comment: Coffee is not just made up of only coffee beans, it contains water as well :P

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki idk why I didn't think of that. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it and close the question.

Comment: But milk also has water in it.

Comment: I think it's just an exception. I've seen all of season 1 now and there are several scenes of different ghouls drinking water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although what you said is write but think about this "Coffee is not just made up of only coffee beans, it contains water as well".